# mark or color empty directories for `ls`

Tags: directory, ls, highlighting

`ls`'s `-F` flag allows to see the types of file and distinguish directories. Is there a way to add a functionality to distinguish an empty directory?

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done with `ls` (at least, as far as I am aware), but you can find empty directories using `find`:

```
find . -type d -empty
```

If the depth matters to you, with GNU `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -empty
```

Comment: @Prometheus. If you need detailed view you may try `ls -ial \`find . -maxdepth 1  -type d -empty\``

Comment: @sundeep - Parsing the output of find like that will break on whitespace, I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I suppose I have to glue them together? I know this may be complicated, but is there a way for me to modify the output of `ls` and then pipe it to another program that will highlight differently? I am thinking of `awk` to replace the match by `find` and then use `grep` to highlight the output, but I do not know how the syntax highlighting is implemented in bash and `grep` does not match the directory name. Also `grep` will erase the highlight done by `ls`. Would you happen to know how to get around these problems?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, to find the non-empty ones:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -not -empty -type d
```